# Two values were deleted, why.?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to create an Array List of numbers and operators excluding white spaces in between.
Now as I want to delete one value somewhere in the List, another value gets deleted.
Here is the **Main function**...

```
System.out.println("Enter the prefix expression");
    z=input.nextLine();
    z=z.replaceAll("\\s+", "");



    while(y < z.length()){
        if(z.charAt(y) == '+'|| z.charAt(y) == '-'|| z.charAt(y) == '/'||z.charAt(y) == '*'){
            list.push(y,z.charAt(y));
            v++; //v=number of operators
        }

        else if(z.charAt(y) == '0'|| z.charAt(y) == '1'|| z.charAt(y) == '2'||
                z.charAt(y) == '3'|| z.charAt(y) == '4'|| z.charAt(y) == '5'||
                z.charAt(y) == '6'|| z.charAt(y) == '7'|| z.charAt(y) == '8'|| z.charAt(y) == '9'){

            list.push(y, z.charAt(y));
            x++;//x=number of numbers

            if(x==2){
                if(z.charAt(v-1) == '*'){
                    list.del(x);
                    x--;
                }
            }//end if

        }//end else if
    y++;    
    }//end while
    System.out.println("y" +y);
    System.out.println("x" +x);
    System.out.println("v" +v);
    list.display();
```

the funcion **del** is here (i was thinking somewhere here is the error but I can't spot it)

```
public void del(int pos){
        for(int i=size;i>=0;i--){
            if(items[i]==items[pos])
            for(int c=i;c<size;c++){
                items[pos]=items[pos+1];
                size--;
            }
        }
    }
```

my input was

```
+-*12
```

and this is the output

```
y5
x2
v3
+-1
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code and going step by step?

Comment: what are you doing here:             for(int c=i;c<size;c++){
                items[pos]=items[pos+1];
                size--;
            } you are iterating but doing the same thing every iteration.

Comment: that line moves the value from one step above the current position where I deleted a data to the vacant array slot

Answer (score 1):

**In method `del`, you need to:**

1. Remove the `size--` inside the inner `for` loop.
2. Add a `break` inside the `if` statement, **after** the inner `for` loop.

**A few other notes:**

1. You can change:

   `if (z.charAt(y)=='+' || z.charAt(y)=='-' || z.charAt(y)=='*' ...)`

   To:

   `if ("+-*/".indexOf(z.charAt(y)) != -1)`
2. You can change:

   `if (z.charAt(y)=='0' || z.charAt(y)=='1' || z.charAt(y)=='2' ...)`

   To:

   `if ("0123456789".indexOf(z.charAt(y)) != -1)`

It will not necessarily improve performance, but it will make your code cleaner...